# modify/replace in LISP

Tags: replace, find, lisp

I have an implementation of a function called modify list shown below but it only works for top level lists.

```
(defun modify-list (old new a-list)
  (cond
   ((null a-list) nil)
   ((eql (car a-list) old) (cons new (modify-list old new (cdr a-list))))
   (T (cons (car a-list)(modify-list old new (cdr a-list))))))
```

CL-USER 16 : 6 > (modify-list 'a 'x '(p a d g c a))
(P X D G C X) <-- GOOD!

CL-USER 17 : 6 > (modify-list 'a 'x '(p a d (g a) c a))
(P X D (G A) C X) <----NOT GOOD!

can anyone help me make this function work on nested lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not working at an higher level? It would make the code simpler...

```
(defun modify (old new x)
  (cond
    ((eq x old) new)
    ((listp x)
     (mapcar (lambda (y) (modify old new y)) x))
    (t x)))
```

Basically instead of assuming `x` must be a list (actually a tree) you just return `new` if `x` is `old`, recursively map if it's a list or otherwise return `x` unchanged...

With this approach also `(modify 'a 'x 'a) --> X` (and that IMO seems right).

Comment: this is why I love stack overflow...always helpful THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
(defun modify-list (old new a-list)
  (cond ((null a-list) nil)
        ((not (listp (car a-list)))
         (if (eql (car a-list) old)
             (cons new (modify-list old new (cdr a-list)))
             (cons (car a-list) (modify-list old new (cdr a-list)))))
        (T (cons (modify-list old new (car a-list))
                 (modify-list old new (cdr a-list))))))
```

I don't have access to a LISP interpreter (anyone can verify the above procedure, please?), so you'll have to test it first!